# Passing data from ASP.NET View to a Controller Async using JS in .NET core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to preface that I know this question has been asked before, but I haven't found a concrete answer that works on .NET core.

I am trying to pass a Model Value back to my controller so I can do some work on it. Can I use Razor URL helpers to send the URL as @Url.Action("Action", "Controller") within the .ajax URL? Also, how can I send data to do work on async? Here is my script file:

```
    $('#ajaxBtn').on('click', function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/AjaxReturn",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",  
            data: 'data: 12345',
            success: function () {
            }
            });

    });
```

Here is my Controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void AjaxReturn(JsonResult data)
    {
        var thisData = data;

    }
```

** I am using this for a responsive js datatable (datatables.net) eg. on a DELETE click I want to pass the ID back to the controller so I can delete the record and then pass back a status.

Comment: Do you mean replace `url: "/Home/AjaxReturn",` with `url: '@Url.Action("AjaxReturn", "Home")',`? - then yes. But it should be `data: { data: 12345 },` and `public void AjaxReturn(string data)` (or `int data`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke your answer works. however, I just realized in my real application this wasn't working because the script lived in its own JavaScript file. In that scenario, how would I use Url tag helpers to redirect?

Comment: There are many ways - e.g. in the main view create a global variable `var url = '@Url.Action(...)';` and in the external file `url: url`. Or in the button add a data attribute `data-url="@Url.Action(....)"` and use `var url = $(this).data('url');` Or create an initialization function for the external file and pass it to the function from the main view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change the parameter in your ajax code.

```
data: '"data": "12345"',
```